# How to make useState's initial value dependent on props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I checked some other answers, but there problem had a different scope.

Here's my react app files situation

Slist.js

```
const Slist = (props) => {
    let [st, updateSt] = useState[[props.arr[0], props.arr[1]]];
    console.log(st);
.
.
```

Dlist.js

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4]
...
// arr is updated to [5,6,7,8] and after that a state setter function is called
...
<Slist arr={arr} />
```

In initial load, there is no problem in Slist.js.

Bue to the Dlist.js's state change due to a button click, it re-renders.
Now, Slist also re-renders but **the initial value in `st` is not updated to the new arr value**.

I believe it is due to the fact that state variables are unaffected by re-render since they are the ones usually causing that (but here it is due to a parent component).

The functionality required is that when the re-render is due to the parent component, it acts as a fresh mounting rather than a re-render, hence intializing the `st` variable again.

Any workaround to this.

Comment: Why would you do this? What's wrong with using props directly?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski because `st` is also subsequently used to trigger a re-render

Comment: It doesn't explain anything for me

Comment: @KonradLinkowski i want to stay on the question, rather than into the best practice.

Comment: Also, sorry, but if you didn't read the entire react documentation before asking the question it means that you didn't search well enough

Comment: If `st` is a computed state then you’re probably better off using useMemo

Comment: I don't know why your question was voted closed for needing more details, the question seems clear enough to me. That said, it's considered a React anti-pattern to duplicate and store passed props into local component state leading to issues such as stale state as you've discovered and are asking how to resolve. You are asking how to fix a problem that is avoided entirely by following industry best practices. Just reference the passed `props.arr` directly in the child `Slist` component and you won't have the issue of needing to synchronize duplicate state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The functionality required is that when the re-render is due to the
> parent component, it acts as a fresh mounting rather than a re-render,
> hence initializing the st [state] variable again.

Given: `<Slist arr={arr} />`

It is generally considered a React anti-pattern to duplicate and store passed props into local component state which leads to possible issues such as stale state. You should reference the passed `arr` prop directly in the component.

```
const Slist = ({ arr }) => {
  cont st = arr.slice(0, 2); // [1,2], or later [5,6], etc...

  ...
};
```

If you absolutely **must** duplicate the `arr` prop locally in state and there's any possibility of it changing during the life of the component then that component should use a `useEffect` hook to "synchronize" the local state.

```
const Slist = ({ arr }) => {
  const [st, setSt] = useState(arr.slice(0, 2)); // first two elements

  useEffect(() => {
    setSt(arr.slice(0, 2));
  }, [arr]);

  ...
};
```

Alternatively you could provide a React key to the `Slist` component such that when the `arr` array values update the `Slist` component will remount.

Example:

```
<Slist
  arr={arr}
  key={JSON.stringify(arr)} // "[1,2,3,4]", and later "[5,6,7,8]", etc...
/>
```

This is the closest you'll get to the requirement of a "fresh mounting", but TBH it's a bit unnecessary with the options provided above. Rerendering a component is less work than tearing down and remounting a component, especially considering you'll be doing the work anyway to extract the first two elements of the passed `arr` array.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using the second approach of `key` as a mount trigger.